# Align different elements to the center - Android

Tags: java, android, image, layout, graphics

I have 5 images side by side in the center, what i'm looking for is a way to set some of them to `visibility="gone"` and the others to realign to the center. Something like this:

[image: % images align]     [image: result wanted of less images also align]

And here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gameEndFirstPlayerName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help! 
Regards Jose

Comment: Is the relative layout necessary?. Seem like you could have a linear layout and center that. What happens with what you have now?

Comment: It's not necessary, i'll try whit linear now. (Post your answer, so you get the points if it works)

Comment: Yeah, the `LinearLayout` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can try a LinearLayout with its orientation set to "horizontal". This should allow the ImageViews to line up side by side.

You can than target each ImageView by their ID `findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` and do something such as `.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />
   </LinearLayout>
```